# SCCM - Change existing deployment deadlines with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sccm

We use SCCM 2016 to install Microsoft updates and have multiple deployments with deadlines of past dates. I'd like to be able to push those deadlines to a future date using a script, as manually changing per deployment with the GUI is time consuming.

[image]

This command shows me the deployments of interest:

```
Get-CMDeployment | Select-Object -Property * | Where-Object {`
$_.SoftwareName -like '*SecurityUpdates*' -and $_.CollectionName -like '*Servers*'
}
```

My research shows I should use `Set-CMSoftwareUpdateDeployment` to modify the deadline of existing deployments. However this is where I'm stuck. According to the following thread, the parameters I should use to define a new deadline are `DeploymentExpireDay` and `DeploymentExpireTime`, as well as make sure the deployment is set to required: 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/11f977f4-09d1-4127-b8ce-7cdb19c88d1b/update-deployment-installation-deadlines-via-powershell?forum=configmanagersecurity

Unsure how to construct a working command, I consulted the cmdlet's MS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/set-cmsoftwareupdatedeployment?view=sccm-ps

Looking at the doco, `DeploymentExpireDay` and `DeploymentExpireTime` aren't listed in the parameters list. Only `DeploymentExpireDateTime` is in the list. However, to add to the confusion, those two parameters are included in the examples whereas DeploymentExpireDateTime is not.

I connect to SCCM like this:

```
#Load Configuration Manager PowerShell Module
Import-module ($Env:SMS_ADMIN_UI_PATH.Substring(0,$Env:SMS_ADMIN_UI_PATH.Length-5) + '\ConfigurationManager.psd1')

#Get SiteCode and set Powershell Drive
$SiteCode = (Get-PSDrive -PSProvider CMSITE).Name
Push-Location "$($SiteCode):\"
```

I tried this:

```
$DeadlineDay = Get-Date -Month 11 -Day 08 -Year 2018
$DeadlineTime = Get-Date -Hour 16 -Minute 0 -Second 0

Set-CMSoftwareUpdateDeployment `
-DeploymentName "Deployment Name" `
-DeploymentType Required `
-DeploymentExpireDay $DeadlineDay `
-DeploymentExpireTime $DeadlineTime
```

But I get this:

```
Set-CMSoftwareUpdateDeployment : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DeploymentExpireDay'.
At line:1 char:104
+ ... ment Name" -DeploymentType Required -DeploymentExpireDay $Deadli ...
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-CMSoftwareUpdateDeployment], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Cmdlets.Deployments.Commands.SetSoftwareUpdateDeploymentCommand
```

So I tried this:

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(20)
Set-CMSoftwareUpdateDeployment `
-DeploymentName "Deployment Name" `
-DeploymentType Required `
-DeploymentExpireDateTime $date
```

But I get this:

```
cmdlet Set-CMSoftwareUpdateDeployment at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject: 
PS SCM:\>
```

Can anyone direct me as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need more information than just the DeploymentName to make this recognizable. Try Specifying The parameter -SoftwareUpdateGroupName  as well was as -DeploymentName so

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(20)
Set-CMSoftwareUpdateDeployment `
-DeploymentName "Deployment Name" `
-SoftwareUpdateGroupName "Software Update Group Name" `
-DeploymentType Required `
-DeploymentExpireDateTime $date
```

If you don't know the software update group name I would go a totally different route.

First get the deployments with

```
Get-CMSoftwareUpdateDeployment
```

I think in your case you will just want all of them anyway but if not you probably have to filter with "**where**" because the -Name parameter seems to be broken.

Then use the objects you get as InputObject for Set-CMSoftwareUpdateDeployment ingoring the name and modifying the time:

```
Get-CMSoftwareUpdateDeployment | where {$_.AssignmentName -eq "Deployment Name"}
| Set-CMSoftwareUpdateDeployment -DeploymentExpireDateTime (Get-Date).AddDays(20)
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I get the software update group names of my existing deployments? I know Get-CMSoftwareUpdateGroup gives me the software update groups in SCCM but I need to know the ones for the existing deployments so I can use SoftwareUpdateGroupName to update the deployment with the same value rather than a new one.

Comment: I just noticed that the softwareupdategroup has no link to the softwareupdatedeployment in the cmdlets. I think it would be possible to get this connection via wmi but as it would be just to call the cmdlet and it can be called in a different way I edited my answer with an alternate route

Comment: Thank you that worked!!! :)))))
Thank you so much for your wonderful help!